# Flickrj - getPublicGroups uncommon return type

Tags: java, flickr, flickrj

Reading the docs for Flickrj 1.2

```
http://flickrj.sourceforge.net/api/com/aetrion/flickr/people/PeopleInterface.html#getPublicGroups(java.lang.String)
```

I'm trying to the public groups for users but it seems the return type is java.util.Collection

```
public java.util.Collection getPublicGroups(java.lang.String userId)
```

And I'm stumped as to how I can get the group names for a user. If I print the output for

```
people.getPublicGroups(userID);
```

I get:

```
[com.aetrion.flickr.groups.Group@3f1179, com.aetrion.flickr.groups.Group@945b95.... etc
```

It's not what I'm after and I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.

The Collection the method getPublicgroups returned was a collection of Groups.

So I assigned the collection to a collection type. Used an iterator to loop the elements in the collection and casted each element to the Group class.